# how can I extend an existing class in typescript

Tags: typescript, bing-maps

I'm using this post to create an infobox class for bing maps api, and I'm creating a definition file for use it with TypeScript.
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/11/30/Bing-Maps-Ajax-7-Adding-InfoBox-Support-via-Extension-to-MicrosoftMaps
  At the end of the the source this article adds two extensions methods to the pushpin class.
  How can I do this in typescript, without to change directly the Pushipin definition file?

thanks,
  Luca

Comment: This is very irritating. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the api source in TypeScript you can't directly inherit from the class.

What you can do however, is just extend it with Javascript as described in the article.

If you have TypeScript interfaces defined for those types you can extend them by just creating another interface with the same name and adding your methods.

Comment: ok, thanks. At the moment I started the development so to use a derived interface is not a problem, but I suppose that when  applied to an existing procedure with bigger code base may be annoyng because I have to cast to the derived interface every time I need to access to the new members